# No test sources found matching the given filter

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I created a deployment pipeline on Azure. I am deploying to a web app. I am using version 2.x. I have unit tests located here:

~\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts

Here is my XAML:

```
steps:
```

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
  testAssemblyVer2: |
  **$(BuildConfiguration)*test*.dll
  **$(BuildConfiguration)*tests*.dll
  **$(BuildConfiguration)**tests*.dll
  !**\obj**
  platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
  configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

My tests do not run and I get this error:

##[warning]No test sources found matching the given filter '**\release*test*.dll,**\release*tests*.dll,**\release**tests*.dll,!**\obj**'

In the log, I see the test project was found:

##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts (directory)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts\AlertActionTests.cs (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts\application.runtimeconfig.json (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts.csproj (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts\GlobalUsings.cs (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts\obj (directory)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts\obj\ConnexReporting.Tests.BLL.Alerts.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts\obj\ConnexReporting.Tests.BLL.Alerts.csproj.nuget.g.props (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts\obj\ConnexReporting.Tests.BLL.Alerts.csproj.nuget.g.targets (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts\obj\project.assets.json (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts\obj\project.nuget.cache (file)
##[debug]  D:\a\1\s\Tests\MyNameSpace.Tests.BLL.Alerts\testhost.runtimeconfig.json (file)